# c pointers and struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
typedef struct { int a; } structC;

typedef struct {
    int b;
    structC *next;
} structB;

typedef struct {
    int c;
    structB *next;
} structA;

structA data1, *datap;
structB data2;
structC data3;
data1.c = 60;
data2.b = 30;
data3.a = 10;
datap = &data1;
data1.next = &data2;
data2.next = &data3;
```

Can you explain to me what the value of `(*(datap->next)).b` and `(*datap).c` will be?

Comment: Start at the inside (`datap` in both or your cases) and work outward.  Given the value assigned to `datap`, what does `datap->next` mean?  Given the value stored there, what does `*(datap->next)` mean?  Given that, what does `(*(datap->next)).b` mean, and what value is stored *there*?  Similarly for the other expression.

Comment: Note that the expressions to be evaluated would be better written as `datap->next->b` and `datap->c` — using the `(*ptr).member` notation is beloved by tutors but is not idiomatic C.

Comment: The question highlights the most important fundamental aspect - the lack of debugging to understand what is happening, by inspecting the value of the pointer reference to the struct, will indicate how it works. Please take the time to read up on the usage of the debugger, set the breakpoint on the line pertinent to the variables and learn to use the debugger going forward. Too often questions posted here are showing that. Also, that is not a [Minimal Reproducible Code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

> Can you explain to me what the value of `(*(datap->next)).b` and `(*datap).c` will be?

- `(*(datap->next)).b`, or simply `datap->next->b`, will be `30`.
  `datap` is set to point at `data1` and `data1->next` points at `data2` and `data2.b` is assigned the value `30`.
- `(*datap).c`, or simply `datap->c`, will be `60`. Again, `datap` points at `data1` and `data1.c` is assigned the value `60`.